# Not able to get sorting event from IgniteUI / igniteui-angular grid

Tags: ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I need to apply alphanumeric sorting on grid but not able to get sorting event from grid.

Answer (score 1):

There are three event emitters that can be used, [topic](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/sorting#sorting-through-the-api) on the subject.

- [sorting](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxgridcomponent.html#sorting) - emitted before sorting expressions are applied
- [sortingDone](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxgridcomponent.html#sortingdone) - Emitted after sorting is completed

  <igx-grid #grid [data]="localData" [autoGenerate]="true" (sortingDone)="sortingDone($event)">
- [sortingExpressionsChange](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxgridcomponent.html#sortingexpressionschange) - Emitted before sorting is performed

Sorting is performed using the `DefaultSortingStrategy` algorithm. Any `IgxColumnCOmponent` or `ISortingExpression` can use a custom implementation of the `ISortingStrategy`.

You can define your own sorting strategy by extending the default one or by implementing `ISortingStrategy`:

1. Example with `CustomSortingStrategy`

```
export class CustomSortingStrategy extends DefaultSortingStrategy {
...
}

...
const strategy = CustomSortingStrategy.instance();

grid.sort({fieldName: 'Name', dir: SortingDirection.Asc, ignoreCase: true, strategy: CustomSortingStrategy.instance()});
```

2. Example with `ISortingStrategy` implementation:

```
export class SortByParityComponent implements ISortingStrategy {
    public sort(data: any[], fieldName: string, dir: SortingDirection) {
        const key = fieldName;
        const reverse = (dir === SortingDirection.Desc ? -1 : 1);
        const cmpFunc = (obj1, obj2) => this.compareObjects(obj1, obj2, key, reverse);
        return data.sort(cmpFunc);
    }
    protected sortByParity(a: any, b: any) {
        return a % 2 === 0 ? -1 : b % 2 === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    protected compareObjects(obj1, obj2, key: string, reverse: number) {
        const a = obj1[key];
        const b = obj2[key];
        return reverse * this.sortByParity(a, b);
    }
}
...

grid.sort({
    fieldName: 'ID',
    dir: SortingDirection.Desc,
    ignoreCase: false,
    strategy: new SortByParityComponent()
});
```

[Here you can find a working sample with CustomSortingStrategy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/igniteui-igxgrid-custom-sorting-strategy-xvxtcg?file=src/app/grid/grid-sorting-sample/grid-sorting-sample.component.ts).